# What makes __destruct called twice in such a simple PHP code?

Tags: php, destructor

```
<?php

class A
{
    static private $_instance = null;

    static public function Init()
    {   
        self::$_instance = new A();
    }   

    function __construct()
    {   
        echo "__construct\n";
    }   

    function __destruct()
    {   
        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
        echo "__destruct\n";
    }   
}
$a = A::Init();
```

Normally, we should get following output: (Yes. I got this result in 2 different servers with PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10 and PHP 5.3.1)

```
__construct
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["function"]=>
    string(10) "__destruct"
    ["class"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["object"]=>
    object(A)#1 (0) {
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
__destruct
```

But, on another server with CentOS release 5.7 and PHP 5.2.17, I got this :

```
    __construct
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(10) "/tmp/1.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(7)
        ["function"]=>
        string(10) "__destruct"
        ["class"]=>
        string(1) "A"
        ["object"]=>
        object(A)#1 (0) {
        }
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(10) "/tmp/1.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(21)
        ["function"]=>
        string(4) "Init"
        ["class"]=>
        string(1) "A"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    __destruct
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["function"]=>
        string(10) "__destruct"
        ["class"]=>
        string(1) "A"
        ["object"]=>
        object(A)#2 (0) {
        }
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    __destruct
```

Why does the function __destruct called twice here? Especially the first time.

I think there might be something special in the configuration, any suggestion?

Thanks.

==================

PS: This problem is not caused by "Singleton design pattern". Same issue appeared with following code :

```
<?php
class A
{
    function __construct()
    {   
        echo "__construct\n";
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
        echo "__destruct\n";
    }
}
$a = new A();
```

Comment: @vascowhite: I feel this is not an *exact* duplicate. Someone who only knows PHP may not understand that example in C++. While the answers may be somewhat similar, the targeted audiences are vastly different.

Comment: Maybe its releated with garbage collector?

Comment: FYI, PHP 5.2.17 on mac this code only fires __destruct once.

Comment: PHP 5.3.5 on mac also works correctly.  Are you sure you have the same code on all servers?

Comment: @TimG Thanks for you test and reply. If you turn on the setting zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = On in your php.ini, you can find twice __destruct in the results. This might be a bug, see my answer blow please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I find the reason.

It might be a bug in PHP 5.2.x :

If

```
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = On
```

then you can see "__destruct" **twice** when execute the code I provide in my question.

This issue has been reported in other versions : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29756

Not affect PHP 5.3 in my test. (PHP 5.3 removed this setting)

Hope this answer will be helpful for some guys later :)