# file_put_contents() messing with updated array values

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies if the title is a bit confusing.

My results below point out what's happening.

---

This question has become pretty extensive, so I'm highlighting these two things here:

See my **update** at the bottom, for a plausible cause.

**Whole file:** (see line 86)  http://codepad.org/oIXaZZaB

---

Here's what's going on:

I have this array which holds counting integers, per language code.

```
$downloads = [
    'all' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ],
    'unique' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ]
];
```

---

The key retrieved from the `$_GET['langCode']` parameter, **always** gets **counted** to the corresponding key in `$downloads['all']`.

I also check if the visitor is unique and has already used the same `$langCode` before. If he hasn't used the same `$langCode` before, the count is also added to the corresponding key in `$downloads['unique']`.

This is done by the following piece of code:

```
$uniqueVisitors = [
    '127.0.0.1' => [ 'en-UK' ]
];


if ($uniqueVisitors == null)
{
    $uniqueVisitors = [
        $ipNew => []
    ];
}



$countUnique = 1;


/*  Check Unique Visitors  */

if (isset($uniqueVisitors[$ipNew]))
{
    if (in_array($langCode, $uniqueVisitors[$ipNew]))
    {
        $countUnique = 0;
    }

    else $uniqueVisitors[$ipNew][] = $langCode;
}

else $uniqueVisitors[$ipNew] = [ $langCode ];



/*  Update Data  */

$downloads['all'][$langCode]++;

if ($countUnique)
{
    $downloads['unique'][$langCode]++;
}


/*  Save Data  */

file_put_contents('data/unique-visitors.json', json_encode($uniqueVisitors));
file_put_contents('data/downloads.json', json_encode($downloads));
```

---

Now the weird part is, when I run the script, sometimes multiple keys get counted, even though `$langCode` contains only one key (eg. `'nl-NL'`)

When using `'en-UK'`, `'en'` is often counted as well.
Same goes for `'fr-FR'` and `'fr-BE'`.
And `'nl-NL'` and `'nl-BE'`.

It mostly happens when the used langCode count is still `0`
But it seems to be happening in random order too.

Now you may think it's due to the **langCodes** used **as** the **keys**, but I've used **zero-index keys as well**, with the same outcome!

**For example:**

```
/*  Retrieved first from JSON file  */

$downloads = [
    'all' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 2,
        'fr-BE' => 1,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ],
    'unique' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 1,
        'fr-BE' => 1,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ]
];

$uniqueVisitors = [
    '127.0.0.1' => [ 'nl-NL', 'fr-BE' ]
];


/*  Result after running script with 'en-UK' langCode  */

$downloads = [
    'all' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 2,
        'fr-BE' => 1,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 1,
        'en'    => 1   // Why is this one counted ?
    ],
    'unique' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 1,
        'fr-BE' => 1,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 1,
        'en'    => 1   // Why is this one counted ?
    ]
];

$uniqueVisitors = [
    '127.0.0.1' => [ 'nl-NL', 'fr-BE', 'en', 'en-UK' ]  //  'en' stored as well ?
];
```

---

**WHOLE FILE:** (see line 86)  http://codepad.org/oIXaZZaB

---

**UPDATE:**

When I don't save the updated data back to their files with the two `file_put_contents()` functions, and just do some testing and dumping, the whole counting does work as expected!

So it appears those two `file_put_contents()` functions, for saving the (correctly) updated data, are somehow interfering, and changing some counts while they are being executed.

But how?!

Does somebody have a better understanding of this unexpected behavior?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

When I leave out `json_encode()` in my `file_put_contents()` functions, I get the "Array to String conversion" error, **twice** for saving my counting data (`$downloads`):

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/downloads/downloads.php on line 89

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/downloads/downloads.php on line 90

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/downloads/downloads.php on line 90
```

---

```
file_put_contents('data/unique-visitors.json', json_encode($uniqueVisitors));
file_put_contents('data/downloads.json', json_encode($downloads));  // This one is called twice!
```

So why is that one executed twice?? There's not even a single loop in there.

---

**UPDATE 3:**

My JSON encoded `$downloads` data shows the updated values correctly.

But as soon as I use `file_put_contents()` to store the updated `$downloads` data, it messes with the updated values. Even when I dump my updated data right before/after using `file_put_contents`, it shows messed up.

Initial `$downloads` array:

```
$downloads = [
    'all' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ],
    'unique' => [
        'nl-BE' => 0,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ]
];
```

Updated values with `$_GET['langCode'] = 'nl-BE'`:

```
$downloads = [
    'all' => [
        'nl-BE' => 1,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ],
    'unique' => [
        'nl-BE' => 1,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ]
];
```

When I try to store the updated array with `file_put_contents()`:

```
$downloads = [
    'all' => [
        'nl-BE' => 2,  // Why this increment?
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ],
    'unique' => [
        'nl-BE' => 1,
        'nl-NL' => 0,
        'fr-BE' => 0,
        'fr-FR' => 0,
        'de-DE' => 0,
        'it-IT' => 0,
        'en-UK' => 0,
        'en'    => 0
    ]
];
```

The weird thing is, is that when I use `file_put_contents`, the updated `$downloads` shows incorrectly updated, when dumping on the same script run (before and after `file_put_contents`). I don't even have to use `file_get_contents` to retrieve the incorrectly saved data.

---

**UPDATE 4: (cause)**

It appears Safari 7 is causing this bug.

Firefox and Chrome are both running this script perfectly.

Where can I report this?

---

**htaccess:**

Same bug still happens without htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can’t reproduce that problem with your code.

Comment: @CBroe Here's the whole file: [http://codepad.org/67sp3INu](http://codepad.org/67sp3INu)

Comment: Updated the whole file, see line 86: [http://codepad.org/Y9aZurkX](http://codepad.org/Y9aZurkX)

Comment: The marked `file_put_contents()` in your *Update 1* and *Update 2* does not get executed twice. You got the error message twice, because `$downloads` contains 2 subarrays, and both of them were failed to be converted to a string. If that array would contain 3 subarrays, you would get the error message 3 times, you may try it out.

Comment: As for your original problem, I was also unable to reproduce your bug, and I also do not see any fundamental flaw in your sample program. The source of the bug must be elsewhere.

Comment: @CMate Thanks for pointing that out. Could it be the JSON encoding of the integer values, maybe?

I'm really baffled with this bug, everything seems fine indeed. I went over it like 8 times.

Comment: @CMate It really is the `file_put_contents` that's messing with my `$downloads` values. I dumped the `json_encode` data, which showed my `$downloads` updated correctly.

Comment: @jlmmns So, just to make it clear. You JSON encoded the `$downloads` array, and dumped the result string, which had the correct value. Then you wrote that string into a file with `file_put_contents`, and the stored string was different from what you dumped? Somehow magically a few integers inside that string were incremented? That sounds kinda unlikely to me, sorry :S Are you sure, that the process only runs once per page load and nobody else visits it while you are debugging it now?

Comment: @CMate That's exactly what's happening. And I'm testing it on my localhost. (see my 3rd update)

Comment: @jlmmns Can you test it on another webserver? Are you testing with the same script you created for us? I am asking because I didn't face the bug you mention when I tried it out.

Comment: @CMate I did. Same results. Have you tried the exact same script as me?

Comment: Hi, I agree with the rest of the people that this script seems to be working as intended, no double runs etc. 
On a different note, proper code for uk is en-GB not en-UK. Hope you find your issue.

Comment: @jlmmns Yes, I just copied what you uploaded at codepad.

Comment: @CMate I just copied it as well, to be certain, same bug.

Comment: @jlmmns If you create a PHP file with a single `file_put_contents` call, which has the hard coded JSON encoded string as its parameter, the bug still holds?

Comment: @jlmmns Also, you wrote, that is bug occurs randomly. Still didn't find any system in it?

Comment: @CMate Single hard coded JSON with `file_put_contents` is working fine.

Comment: @CMate When copying the script from codepad again, 'nl-BE' was counted twice, and for some reason 'it-IT' was counted as well.

Comment: Given that you've found the answer, can you please post and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I was also unable to reproduce your bug. It seems to me that your script is called twice (see item in 'all' is incremented but not in 'unique'.

There is no problem with `file_put_contents()`. You can verify this by adding something like this to your script:

```
<?php

mail('you@domain.tld', 'script executed at '.time(), '');

// your code ...
```

I recommend to copy your script, remove all html code and **execute it in a terminal with dummy data**:

```
php yourscript.php
```

Here is my code: http://codepad.org/XhS6uEz1

and you will see that it behaves correctly.

Additionally you can disable some [php module that could be responsible for such bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455103/what-makes-destruct-called-twice-in-such-a-simple-php-code) but i think that is not the problem.

Comment: How is it possible that my script is called twice? It doesn't make sense.
I'm even using `exit;` at the end of the update part.

Comment: And as soon as I use `file_put_contents`, my updated array holds incorrectly updated values. Without using `file_put_contents`, it dumps out the correctly updated values.

Comment: your entire script is called twice (and the exit too). its like press f5 in your browser. please run it in your terminal.

Comment: It works fine in terminal, indeed. But I have absolutely no idea how my script could be running multiple times on localhost. (and on another server on the web)

Comment: And just to be clear: 'unique' only needs to increment when the `langCode` is not set for the ip-address. So it will stay just 1 for me.

Comment: have your tried to remove all the html from the file (there shouldn't be the ?>) ?

Comment: which php version? which browser are you using? do you have firebug installed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016784/pages-load-twice-on-firefox)? try to load your page with another browser or via the terminal with curl or wget.

Comment: Good lord, it's just Safari 7 that's causing the bug. Firefox 25.0.1 is working properly, as well as Chrome 31.0.1650.63, with HTML.

Could this be a known bug for the new Safari 7?

Comment: No. I dont think so. Safari is requesting a favicon.ico and the request may forwarded to you php script, so there a two. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926943/site-is-called-twice

Comment: I'm not using a favicon on that page, and it isn't the index page. It's inside a subdirectory. I removed the favicon from the root, to make sure, but I still have the bug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42755/discussion-between-besnik-and-jlmmns)

Comment: Do you have any iframe/img tags without src? they may cause double page request

Comment: single stepping with Xdebug may help in this case to track the issue.

Comment: @apoq No iframes or images used.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your server access logs to see if you can determine the source of the 2nd call to the script.  I've had things like this with plugins installed, debuggers or plugins that check your page load speed can call the page again.

Comment: I tried enabling MAMP's access logs, as explained in [this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/162233/how-to-enable-non-error-apache-log-on-mamp), but the log file won't appear.

However, I've removed all my extensions and plugins in Safari 7, with the same result.